# What exactly does this git push statement mean?

Tags: git

`git push -f origin master:release/production`

It looks like it's making the remote `release/production` the same as the remote `master`. However, even when the two remote branches are different, it says `Everything up-to-date`.

I have to checkout local master, pull it, then run the command. This way, the updates get pushed to the remote `release/production`.

What exactly does this command mean? Does `master` refer to the local `master`, the local `origin/master`, or the remote `master`?

Also, if I want to make the remote `release/production` the same as the remote `master`, what command should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What exactly does this command mean?

It forcibly pushes the **local** branch `master` to the remote repository `origin` to the remote branch `release/production`.

> Also, if I want to make the remote release/production the same as the remote master, what command should I use?

You cannot move branches at the remote repository from the local repository. If you have ssh access to the server you can do it there:

```
ssh origin-host
cd /path/to/remote/repo
git reset --soft release/production
exit
```

(Soft reset because the repository is most certainly bare, it doesn't have the working directory).

If you don't have ssh access the commands are:

```
git fetch origin master:master # Update local master from remote
git push -f origin master:release/production
```